# Why does mp.Pool fast fail, but ProcessPoolExecutor doesn't?

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing

1.

```py
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(foo, user_number, user_id)
                   for user_number, user_id in enumerate(user_ids, start=1)]

        for future in as_completed(futures):
            future.result()
```

2.

```py
    pool = Pool()
    results = [pool.apply_async(foo, args=(user_number, user_id))
               for user_number, user_id in enumerate(user_ids, start=1)]
    for result in results:
        result.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

3.

```py
    pool = Pool()
    results = [pool.apply_async(foo, args=(user_number, user_id))
               for user_number, user_id in enumerate(user_ids, start=1)]
    try:
        for result in results:
            result.get()
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

`foo` does some job then raises a Value error.

When using the first example, I only get the exception after all futures finished.
with the second example, I get the exception as soon as the first job fails.
With the third example, it acts similar to the first

How can I fail fast and still clean the resources before exiting?

Why does this happen? according to docs, `as_completed` returns futures as soon as they are finished, and calling `future.result()` should raise the exception.

Python version is 3.6.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Python cannot safely cancel jobs that have already started. The difference lies just in what you tell Python to do:

- Case 1: The exception *is* raised by `future.result()`. Then, control flow breaks out of the `with` statement, and `ProcessPoolExecutor.__exit__` is triggered. This, by default, waits for all pending jobs to finish, so execution hangs until that is the case.
- Case 2: The Python interpreter exits immediately when encountering the exception. But that doesn't mean that your jobs have stopped running! You just never wait for them to finish.
- Case 3: After the exception is raised, you call `pool.join()`, which is more or less the same as what's going on in case 1. Execution waits for the jobs to finish, then exits.

You can check what exactly is going on in case 2 with this script:

```py
import signal
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def throw():
    raise ValueError()


def foo():
    def sigterm_handler(*args):
        print('received sigterm')
        raise SystemExit()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)

    while True:
        print('still alive')
        time.sleep(0.1)

pool = Pool()
results = [pool.apply_async(throw), pool.apply_async(foo)]
time.sleep(1)

for result in results:
    result.get()

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

On OSX, this outputs:

```sh
$ python mp_test.py
still alive
still alive
still alive
still alive
still alive
still alive
still alive
still alive
still alive
still alive
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "mp_test.py", line 8, in throw
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    result.get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError
still alive
received sigterm
```

So, the workers receive the `SIGTERM` signal when the interpreter exits (behavior might be OS dependent, though). Note that `SIGTERM` *can* be ignored (e.g. by a third-party library you are using in your workers), so there is no guarantee that your workers actually exit in this case.

---

Now, if you have long-running jobs and **are sure they can be safely cancelled** (e.g., because they don't do any I/O), you can use something like this to emulate the behavior of case 2:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    try:
        futures = [executor.submit(foo, user_number, user_id)
                   for user_number, user_id in enumerate(user_ids, start=1)]

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            future.result()

    except Exception:
        # abort workers immediately if anything goes wrong
        for process in executor._processes.values():
            process.terminate()
        raise
```

This will send `SIGTERM` to all jobs that are still running when the exception is encountered, then raise the exception (and wait for all processes to finish, so you can be sure they have stopped). Again, this is not a graceful exit - it can and will lead to data-loss or dangling resources when you interrupt during I/O.

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) say this about the `terminate` method:

> Terminate the process. On Unix this is done using the SIGTERM signal; on Windows TerminateProcess() is used. Note that exit handlers and finally clauses, etc., will not be executed.
>
> Note that descendant processes of the process will not be terminated – they will simply become orphaned.
>
> Warning
>
> If this method is used when the associated process is using a pipe or queue then the pipe or queue is liable to become corrupted and may become unusable by other process. Similarly, if the process has acquired a lock or semaphore etc. then terminating it is liable to cause other processes to deadlock.

Comment: So let's say ```foo``` creates a new file and sometimes fails, with option 2 even after failing and exiting the main thread, there will still be background process creating files?

Comment: And is there a way to finish all running process, but at least not start any new one after one job failed?

Comment: There are no new jobs being queued up after the first exception. The only jobs that are running after that are those already in the call queue, because they can't be cancelled. Source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L550-L553

Comment: Concerning your first question: They may or may not continue to run. On my OS, the workers receive `SIGTERM` when the interpreter exits. But you never know unless you wait for them or terminate them yourself.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a script that you can use to see what's happening in case 2 in your environment.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, the problem is that all jobs get put up in the call_queue before the first exception happens. I ended up using an `Event` to tell the other process to exit right after the start.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Alternatively, you can try and modify my example to send `SIGINT` to the workers (instead of `terminate` / `SIGTERM`). `SIGINT` is functionally equivalent to a `KeyboardInterrupt` and allows for a graceful exit.